# Blazemeter working mechanism in background

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I am new in performance testing. I want to know how does Blazemeter internally work. How does it distribute load on multiple regions. How does it collate final report? how does it manage multiple thread groups etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) tests execution BlazeMeter:

1. Kicks off a virtual machine using one of the following cloud providers:

   - [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/)
   - [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/)
   - [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)
   - or it's also possible to install BlazeMeter agent on your [private computer(s)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421655-Creating-a-Private-Location)
2. Installs JMeter slave(s) on the cloud machines
3. Installs JMeter master on the controller machine
4. Starts the test so it's basically [JMeter's Distribured Execution Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) but you don't have to worry about installing Java, JMeter, configuring [RMI ports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote), etc.

The real time reporting consists of 2 parts:

1. Open source [Taurus framework](https://gettaurus.org/) which sends metrics to [BlazeMeter API](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732689-BlazeMeter-REST-APIs)
2. Proprietary BlazeMeter technology which aggregates, processes and visualizes data.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, Blazemeter works with Tauras, it parameterizes multiple.JMX files in a single YAML script and runs the JMeter scripts using a YAML script. It passes the JMeter scripts into your YAML script and views the results on the Taurus console for better insights.

Below are links that will be helpful to understand more about tauras:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wVSbalE_Nh8&t=280s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DN0VNnG-lzs